# Can some one give me an example of cross correlation's high value where template matches with image?

Tags: image-processing

I find it difficult to understand how result of cross correlation of a patch of image and image is high at matching point? what if patch contains small values and other non matching point contains very high values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this [document here](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture07.pdf). If I understood your question clearly, then you need to take out the mean from the image. After that probably you would find cross-correlation for the matching patch.